# Google Cloud Functions API exceeded

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google Cloud Functions in my Firebase project. There are altogether 26 functions (including HTTPS, DB, pub/sub triggers).

On deploying all of these 26 functions together, I get `HTTP Error: 429, Quota for Google Cloud Functions API exceeded for project` messages.

If I re-run the deploy (I'm using `firebase deploy --only functions`), the messages are still there but for different functions.

Some of these functions have not been updated for days.

This makes me selectively re-deploy those functions that were not successful.

I'm on the Spark (free) plan.

**Is this expected behavior? Can I increase this quota?**

Comment: You seem to have used up the free quota on your project. To increase your quota, upgrade your project to one of the paid plans.

Comment: FWIW--I'm seeing the error for the first time also.  Odd that we both exceeded the free Spark plan quota on the same day.

Comment: FWIW2--I no longer get the error after upgrading to Blaze plan.  It seems that whatever quota was being exceeded is not documented or listed in the [pricing plan descriptions](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?gclid=Cj0KEQjwmIrJBRCRmJ_x7KDo-9oBEiQAuUPKMkU_d1rU9xowa4BhRXdA10vR9heNy1fAlLuqsKibg_caAlUq8P8HAQ).

Comment: Thanks both. It would be interesting to know what quota was reached - looks like whatever it is, it's deployment related.